# Text style is crashing my map

Tags: openlayers

I have a styling function like this:

```
var customStyleFunction = function( feature, resolution ) {
       var resultStyles = [];

       (other styles, line, point, etc)

       var featureText = new ol.style.Style({
           text: new ol.style.Text({
               text: feature.getProperties().label,
               scale : 1,
           })
       });  

       resultStyles.push( featureText );
       return resultStyles;
}
```

When I have few polygons, All goes ok.

[image]

but when I try to add a vector layer with some more polygons, my map crashes:

[image]

the viewport will reduce every time I try to move or zoom the map. What I have done wrong?

Comment: Ok. found the problem. Sometimes `feature.getProperties().label` may come `null` and it is causing the map to crash...